# list view border design in android

Tags: android, listview

I am created list view its working fine but how to set border on every item like below screen please any one help me how do that

how to design border line design on every item  i mention it circle shape

[image]

Comment: its a background image for the list item and they have the padding to the layout

Comment: not padding space i am asking about border breaking line design on every list item@dileep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new shape drawable to use for the background and set the stroke `android:dashGap` and `android:dashWidth` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#666666"
    android:dashGap="2dp"
    android:dashWidth="8dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="8dp"
    android:left="8dp"
    android:right="8dp"
    android:top="8dp" />

</shape>
```

> **Note:** create the drawable xml file in the `res/drawable` folder

if you want rounded corners add:

```
 <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
```

Comment: where i need to create this xml file@touchBoarder

Comment: create a new resource file in the folder res/drawable and past in the above xml.

Comment: thaq u i got this @mr.TouchBoarder